# Is this a bug in angular? The checkbox will not reset twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to check a radio button using another element. It works the first time but just won't work second time around I just cannot see what the problem is!

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="miniC">

Yes 
<input type="radio" name="joint" value="yes" ng-checked="!nochecked" ng-click="" />
No 
<input type="radio" name="joint" value="no" ng-checked="nochecked" ng-click="" />

<br>
<br>

<a href="#" ng-click="nochecked = true">check no</a>               

</div>
```

When I click the 'check no' anchor tag I expect the 'no' radio button to be checked. This works the first time. However second time it doesn't. To recreate do this...

1) check 'yes'
2) click link that says 'check no' (observe no checked)
3) cick 'yes'
4) click the link that says 'check no' (observe nothing happens :-[ )

The fiddle is here....

http://jsfiddle.net/5pWK2/

Is this a bug in angular?

Comment: please use <br/> instead of <br>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set `nochecked` to `true` and not set to `false` again. It is assigned to `true` forever

This is right approach:

```
Yes 
<input type="radio" value="false" name="joint" ng-model="nochecked" />
No 
<input type="radio" value="true"  name="joint"  ng-model="nochecked" />

<a href="#" ng-click="nochecked = 'true'">check no</a>
```

and set initial value in controller:

```
$scope.nochecked = 'true';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DEhK9/2/

Comment: Thanks sorry yeah I was thinking about the elements rather than the model binding.....

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `ng-model` and assigning that to the `value` attribute of the radio:

```
Yes 
<input type="radio" name="joint" value="yes" ng-model="nochecked" ng-click="" />
No 
<input type="radio" name="joint" value="no" ng-model="nochecked" ng-click="" />

<br>
<br>

<a href="#" ng-click="nochecked = 'no'">check no</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an angular bug, think about what is happening, angular is watching the value of nonchecked in the scope, and it will react whenever it value changes.

First execution, it assigns true to this value, and so it reacts and shows in the view, but following times you never reset this value, so no change in the scope, no change in the view.

Add in the click of the radio to update this value accordingly and it will work.

Regards,

PS. As other answers specify, adding ng-model, will update the scope based in the values of the radio-set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
Yes 
<input type="radio" name="joint" ng-checked="!nochecked" ng-click="nochecked=false" />
No 
<input type="radio" name="joint" ng-checked="nochecked" ng-click="nochecked=true" />

<br>
<br>

<a href="#" ng-click="nochecked = true">check no</a>
```